# My javascript doesn't work in mobile (phonegap)

Tags: phonegap

I made a really simple one page website with bootstrap and javascript. After that, i used phonegap and made a mobile version of it. But when i open the apk file in my phone my website doesn't work fine.

(like menu doesnt open or when i click submit button my modal doesn't appear etc.)

How can i solve this?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle and/or your code and explain your issue in details if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome debugger to view your code executing on the device and see what's wrong from there. Refer to here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap for details on how to do this.  It's only when you know what the actual error is that we can help you. "Not working" isn't enough for us to help.